# Serializing JSON ReadingOptions with inconsistent output in Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization

I'm working on a pet project where I am serializing JSON using the `JSONSerialization` class and `jsonObject(with:options:)`. The object is unusable until cast into a Dictionary `[String: Any]` or an Array `[Any]`. This is where the inconsistency occurs. The following is a method from one of my classes. The input is tested and valid.

```
private static func parse(data: Data) -> [JSONDictionary]? {
    do {
        let options = JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions() // rawValue = UInt 0
        let otherOptions: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = [] // rawValue = UInt 0
        let jsonAny = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: otherOptions)
        if let array = jsonAny as? [String: Any] {
            print(array)
        }
    } catch {
        return nil
    }

    return nil
}
```

Both of the `ReadingOption` objects are valid and produce valid output that can be properly cast, and `print(array)` is called.

However, when I use the following, invalid output is returned and can not be cast properly. Note `options` in the `jsonObject` call has an equivalent value to `otherOptions` in the above example.

```
private static func parse(data: Data) -> [JSONDictionary]? {
    do {
        let jsonAny = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let array = jsonAny as? [String: Any] {
            print(array) // never called
        }
    } catch {
        return nil
    }

    return nil
}
```

I thought because they have equivalent values that I could use them in place of each other. But that is not the case. Is this a bug, or am I using this incorrectly?

*Edit: here is the dataset being used https://www.govtrack.us/api/v2/role?current=true&role_type=senator*

Comment: Are you saying that when you pass the same `data` to the two different versions of this function, the first gives you a valid value for `array` but the second one does not? That certainly should not be the case. Both pass the same value for the `options` parameter.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, the only thing that changes between the two calls is the `options` parameter. The `data` parameter is the exact same.

I suspect it is a bug but I'm making sure I'm not misusing OptionSet first.

Comment: There should be no difference in creating a variable with a value of an empty option set and pass that versus directly passing the empty option set. There must be some other difference in your tests.

Comment: @rmaddy It seems that there may some inconsistencies with the test, yes... I'll further investigate but for the time being it seems that vadian's answer below is the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reading options are irrelevant. In Swift `ReadingOptions` are only useful if the expected result is **not** array or dictionary.

**If the expected type is array or dictionary omit the `options` parameter**.

The inconsistency is that your return type is an array (`[JSONDictionary]`) but the actual type is a dictionary.

```
private static func parse(data: Data) -> JSONDictionary? {
    do {
        let jsonAny = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
        if let jsonDictionary = jsonAny as? JSONDictionary {
            return jsonDictionary 
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
    return nil
}
```

It's recommended to hand over an error of a throwing method

```
enum SerializationError : Error {
   case typeMismatch
}

private static func parse(data: Data) throws -> JSONDictionary {
    let jsonAny = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
    guard let jsonDictionary = jsonAny as? JSONDictionary else { throw SerializationError.typeMismatch }
    return jsonDictionary 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am definitely changing the code to use `.jsonObject(with:)` instead. I am still very curious as to why the inconsistency is occurring.

Comment: This doesn't really address the issue. The OP claims they should be getting back a dictionary in both cases. The *only* difference is how the options are passed to `jsonObject`. Both are passing `[]` which is the default. Both should work exactly the same. And this answer is no different in that regard other than relying on the default instead of explicitly passing in `[]`.

Comment: Here is the dataset used: https://www.govtrack.us/api/v2/role?current=true&role_type=senator -- it is a dictionary, not an array (editing main post for clarity).